# How does a HT motor deliver profit

Tags: power-consumption

How is HT motor more beneficial over a motor of same power delivery.
If the power delivered remains same in both types of motor for a given power delivered to shaft, how is one more useful than the other.?

Comment: Why do you assume that the HT motor is more beneficial? For what application? In order to help you, we must know the reasoning behind your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that this is an Indian student homework question and by HT you mean High Tension (high voltage).

If you assume that your local utility supplies HT (say tens of kV) to your factory property and bills for the energy that crosses onto factory property, consider what losses is the factory paying for in each case... draw a sketch of how the power flows and your answer should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

The higher voltage motor and the associated power distribution and control equipment have lower losses due to operation at lower current. However, the equipment is more expensive and the maintenance personnel may need to be more highly trained.